# ESlint is not working in Atom - React Native

Tags: react-native, npm, atom-editor, eslint

I want Atom editor to show errors but ESLint is not working.

Steps I followed are:

-> Installed both packages: '**linter-eslint**' & '**linter**' in atom.

-> Via command prompt, inside project directory I have run

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-config-rallycoding
```

-> Then created configuration file '**.eslintrc**' file in project.

-> In **.eslintrc** file I have added following code:

```
{ 
   "extends": "rallycoding"
}
```

P.S: Operating System : Windows 10 & 
Above steps are followed by instructor in Udemy's Best Seller Course **"The Complete React Native and Redux Course"**